# how to limit search to certain folder AND certain file types (more than one) in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

consider the following files and folders structure:

```
  head.html
  folder1
      1.css (this file is inside "folder1")
      1.html
      1.php
  folder2
      1.css
      1.html
      1.php
      subfolder2 (this is a subfolder inside "folder2")
          1.css
          1.html
          1.php
          deepsub2 (a folder inside "subfolder2" that is inside "folder2")
              1.css
              1.html
              1.php
```

to clarify the structure:

- "folder1", "folder2", "subfolder2" and "deepsub2" are folders.
  all the rest are files.
- "1.css", "1.html" and "1.php" under that appear under a folder, for example "folder1" are inside
  that folder.
- "head.html" is in the root folder.
- "subfolder2" is a folder inside "folder2" and "deepsub2" is a folder inside "subfolder2".

**What i'm trying to do** is search the word "viewport" **in "folder2"** and anything beneath it (including its subfolders), which means I don't want search in other folders (folder1 for example) or the root (head.html for example)

I also want to limit the search for file types: **.html and .css**

I **DON'T want to specifically exclude .php as a file type** because consider that sometimes I don't know what other file types there are in the structure and they can be t0o many to exclude, so I want to only to use a list of file types to include rather.

after reading the docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options

the best I could come up with is using the following in the "files to include" input:

`./folder2/**/*.css,./folder2/**/*.html`

but it doesn't seem efficiant enough because i'm using the "folder2" path part for every file type.
is there a better way?

I'm using VScode Version: 1.65.0 by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

`./folder2/**/*.{css,html}`  NO spaces in the `{...}` extensions or it won't work

from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options:

> `{}` to group conditions (for example `{**/*.html,**/*.txt}` matches
> all HTML and text files)

Comment: yep, that was the efficiency I was looking for. I thank you very much. marked as answer.